# Custom Java Code Folding for Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, folding

I spent a lot of time googling, now I'll try it here. Some of you might know the "regions" available in Microsoft Visual Studio, which allow you to collaps an arbitrary part of your code to just a single line, more or less like

```
// [start] The text which will appear instead of the collapsed part
...
A bunch of lines of code
...
// [end]
```

In my opinion this is a really fine way to comment code, but it doesn't seem to be available for Java and Eclipse. However, there *was* a plugin for that ( [click](http://themindstorms.blogspot.com/2006/09/eclipse-api-and-code-folding.html) ) but it doesn't work with Eclipse Helios.

So here's my question: Do you know a way to achieve this kind of code folding in a current version of eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this one - http://incubator.apache.org/isis/ide-support.html
It claims to be working on Eclipse 3.5, so there is a chance it will work on 3.6/3.7 (you will have to try).
Hope that helps!

Comment: Btw, it's adding folding for blocks, not for random selections. But I think it's better than nothing ;)

Comment: The installation instructions says "unzip into Eclipse's plugins folder". Don't, please! Use the `dropins/` folder instead.

Comment: @sgibly: Apache Isis is for block folding, but they use a new version of the coffee-bytes plugin I mentioned above. And this one is able to do arbitrary folding for user defined comments - I tested it and works fine.

Comment: It appears that this is no longer available? http://isis.apache.org/other/eclipse-plugin.html